# Duplicate text in mail, why?

Tags: email, smtp

If I open up the source of an e-mail from an application, then I can see that the main body part is two times in it.

What could possibly cause such a thing? The MUA's showing the sent text only once, only the mail source shows that for some reason the application put the text in the mail twice.

Comment: How do the MIME headers look like in the source?

Comment: From "an application". Which application? It's how this application builds the message. If it's a common application, we could help with its configuration. If it's something custom, you should ask its developers.

Answer (score 2):

It's common for email clients to include text and html version of the message so users of plain text only mail clients or who disabled html can still read the email.

In this case, the sender would include the messages with multipart/alternate MIME, which signals to the recipient's MUA that the two versions contains equivalent content, just in different formats, and the recipient can pick whichever format they can and are willing to display.

Comment: yes, we were thinking of this, but the two text is exactly the same, contain HTML, strange

Comment: Could be a misconfigured milter as well.  I would check any custom modules on the mail server, such as amivisd, etc.